# UI getting strucked in the quiz app

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, android-edittext, textview, android

I am trying to do a quiz app ,which will match telugu letters with english letters,my UI will have a top text view which will display the telugu letter , the user has to type the corresponding english letter in the edit text ,and after that screen will refresh and new questions  will appear after that 6 seconds ,at the end i want to display the statistics how many right answers and wrong answers and just display all the wrong answers and they have made .But my ui is getting strucked and after some 60 seconds ,the thing like A-> is appearing.

```
    package vamsi.saran.koli.deepti;
    public class LetterQuiz extends Activity {
int rightAnswer = 0, wrongAnswer = 0;
TextView finalResult;
TextView top, eval;
Typeface font;
EditText answer;

String english[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X",
        "Y", "Z" };
String telugu[] = { "ఎ", "బి", "సి", "డి", "ఇ", "ఎఫ్", "జి", "ఎచ్", "ఐ",
        "జె", "కె", "ఎల్", "య్మ్", "యెన్", "వొ", "పి", "క్యు", "ఆర్",
        "ఎస్", "టి", "యు", "వి", "డబల్యు", "ఎక్స్", "వై", "జెడ్" };
int number;
static Random rand = new Random();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_letter_quiz);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/NotoSansTelugu-Bold.ttf");

    top = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.telugu);
    eval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eval);
    answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
    finalResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finale);
    finalResult.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    quiz();

}

public void quiz() {
    int wronganswers[] = new int[10];
    int j = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
        int i;
        number = rand.nextInt(25 - 0) + 0;
        top.setTypeface(font);
        top.setTextSize(40.f);
        top.setText(telugu[number]);
        eval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eval);
        SystemClock.sleep(6000);
        answer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answer);
        String user = answer.getText().toString();
        for (i = 0; i < english.length; i++) {
            if (user.equalsIgnoreCase(english[i])) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == number) {
            eval.setText("Right Answer");
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            rightAnswer++;
        } else {
            eval.setText("Wrong Answer");
            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            wrongAnswer++;
            wronganswers[j] = number;
            j++;
        }
        SystemClock.sleep(2000);

    }
    finalResult
            .setText("No of right answers" + rightAnswer
                    + "\nNo of wrong answers" + wrongAnswer
                    + "\nletters to review");
    String review = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < wronganswers.length; i++)
        review = english[wronganswers[i]] + "->" + telugu[wronganswers[i]]
                + "\n";
    finalResult.setText(review);
    top.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    eval.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    answer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    finalResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.letter_quiz, menu);
    return true;
 }

  }
```

and my xml is

```
               <RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LetterQuiz" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/telugu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/telugu"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="71dp"
    android:ems="10"
     >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/eval"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/telugu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

<TextView 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/finale"


    />
```

Comment: why do you use that cumbersome loop with `break` in order to check for correctness of answer? do your telugu letter positions in array `telugu[]` correspond to english letter positions in array `english[]` ? if so, then filter out input strings other than single english character, and use this `int idx = -97 + (int)user.toLowerCase().charAt(0); if(idx==number){ //success }`

Comment: yes they do(both telugu letter positions and english letter positions, mean the same), and i have modified the solution according to you ,but still can't figure out ,what's wrong ! UI is still strucked

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're iterating through `wronganswers[]` using `wronganswers.length` but it is always 10, regardless of whether you've done errors or not. you should use `wrongAnswer` instead.

use this:

```
finalResult.setText("No of right answers" + rightAnswer
                    + "\nNo of wrong answers" + wrongAnswer
                    + "\nletters to review\n");

 String review = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < wrongAnswer; i++)
        review = english[wronganswers[i]] + "->" + telugu[wronganswers[i]] + "\n";
    finalResult.append(review);
```

Comment: @VamsiPavanMahesh what exactly happens? If UI is too slow then launch your quiz function inside of Runnable in order not to do slow down UI thread

Comment: it skips everything and says i have attempted everything wrong(even i have not touched) and finally displays the screen ..